# Connect to Azure Text Analytics from Console App without await

Tags: console-application, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to call an Azure API (Text Analytics API) from a C# console application with a HttpRequest and I do not want to use any DLLs or await

but using the below snippet I am receiving "Bad Request". Can someone help me where it is going wrong.

```
public static void ProcessText()
        {            
            string apiKey = "KEY FROM AZURE";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var requestUri = "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment?" + queryString;
            //HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I really love Azure. It is the best cloud platform");

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {               
                //content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }           
        }
```

Comment: “*I do not want to use any DLLs or await*” What’s the reason for this arbitrary requirement? Why not use “DLLs or await” if it’s the correct or easiest way to do things??

Comment: in some of the applications we may not be able to leverage DLLs but can leverage HttpRequests

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - almost all applications of this type "leverage DLLs", not sure how you would get any functionality without them... your response also doesn't really answer why you can't use the `await` operator, either - it's literally an operator built-in to the language.

Comment: @esqew I agree, but I want to try sync call

Answer (score 0):

```
        string apiKey = "<<Key from Azure>>";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", apiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var requestUri = "https://**eastus**.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment?" + queryString;
        //HttpResponseMessage response;

        var body = new
        {
            documents = new[]
            {
            new
            {
                ID="1", text="I really love Azure. It is the best cloud platform"
            } 
            }
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        dynamic item = null;
        using (var con = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {               
            //content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = client.PostAsync(requestUri, con).Result;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string res = string.Empty;
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    res = result.Result;
                }
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(res);
            }
        }
```

Hi All, I could able to get the API output using the above approach